# Does "fils mineur" mean a son of minor age?

Tags: phrase

I'm studying a marriage record from *Province de Québec* today and just need to check my understanding of a *fils mineur* at marriage.  This caught my attention because everything I can find about the groom says he was either 19 or 20 years old when he got married.

Did I misunderstand the marriage record?  Or is this a clerical glitch?

Comment: Is the *fils* the groom? Or does the marriage record state that the groom has a son (in which case it makes perfect sense that the son is a minor)? Posting an excerpt of the record would help.

Comment: It's the way they state the groom and his parents.  Usually, entre ... fils mineur de...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might have found an answer on my own.

The Government of Canada website has a civil law history section that mentions the age of majority was 21 years during 1782 to 1971, and before that it was 25 years.  So there is a historical subtlety to the meaning.